# How to monitor the use of Nootropics?

Tags: brain

How do you monitor the use of nootropics?

What is a good process to measure both: side-effects and any improvements.
Where can I find resources with scientific and tested data of short and long term usage of various Nootropics? (I'm using google as well)

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed‎)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of measuring the effect of nootropics would be the same as for any other drug: Do a double blinded placebo study and the follow the parameters you hope to influence. For example do "brain tests" if you want to test for enhanced brain function. If there is any function of your drug in the body, you will see a difference between the treatment and the control group. You could start by reading the Wikipedia article about [Nootropics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nootropic) which is quite exhausting and also has quite a lot of references and go on with these two papers "[Does taking vitamin, mineral and fatty acid supplements prevent cognitive decline? A systematic review of randomized controlled trials.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18721399)" and "[Cognition enhancers between treating and doping the mind.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18353672)"

Comment: Thanks :) I think I asked the wrong question... should have asked which variables I should track. I've marked your question as correct anyway, as it answers what I asked. Thanks

Comment: Obviously, the choice of variables should depend on what the drug 'affects'. Anyway, you wrote a good answer to a poor question :)

Comment: About which drug effects are you thinking?